# Automated walking animation

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm looking to create clip of someone walking, I have a full body character and I can happily rig this completely.

However.. rather than spend a lot of time perfecting this character walking, is there a website that will apply a walking animation to a pre-rigged (or unrigged) character that I can import into blender? So I can then spend the time on texturing, camera, environment etc.

Once I have a walking animation, I'm looking to animate the face on top of this (I'm hoping that the metarig can work in accordance with the auto-animation).

Comment: Hello, Mixamo offers walk cycles animation

Comment: [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/)'s animations have no face animation included and it has it's own auto-rig. If you want to add a face animation with Rigify then you need to retarget the animation. There is an add-ons for such tasks like the [Blender Expy Kit addon](https://youtu.be/ars_rEC3oP8) (github: https://github.com/pKrime/Expy-Kit)

Comment: [Here](https://youtu.be/r3RoHNOzj7k) is the official one of the add-on's author. And [here](https://youtu.be/7WDBqXTAKDg) is one about Mixamo and Rigify's Face rig.

Comment: This site is a high quality database of knowledge about blender, "*Spend a lot of time learning/testing/redoing*"  is exclusively what we do here. If you just want a third party tool or a link to a site then this off topic here, I'm afraid. Could you rephrase your question to read like an enquiry about using Blender?

Comment: Thank you to all above.
@Blunder This look exactly what I need to learn about and apply – thank you!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I appreciate this comment and I've adjusted the question for clarity.